# Controlling component data across multiple routes

Tags: ember.js

I have a mapping app that has a full-screen map with a sidebar for information. This app has two routes:

- one route that should display a list of places with markers on the map, for example `/places/`
- one route that should display a single place with that particular place's marker centered on the map, for example `places/1/`

My map is currently a `Component` that is in `application.hbs`, so it is "outside" of the route templates and persists across route changes. It looks something like:

```
<div class="page">
  <aside class="sidebar">
      {{outlet}}
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    {{places-map ... }}
  </div>
</div>
```

and my routes looks something like:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('place', { path: "/place/:place_id" });
  this.route('places');
});
```

So while I have all this set up and working (I can see a list of places and move a single particular place, in both cases with the map in the "background"), I can't understand how my routes can feed information to my component or simply how my routes can communicate with the component that is sitting "outside" of their context?

Is this a possible pattern with Ember and is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditto on what [@GerDner said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226878/916734) about data-down-actions-up.

Starting from the top:

**application/controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  somethingDownFromController: null
});
```

**application/route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  set
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    sendSomethingUp(something) {
      set(this.controllerFor('application'), 'somethingDownFromController', something);
    }
  }
});
```

**application/template.hbs**

```
<div class="page">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    {{outlet}}
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    {{places-map
      something=somethingDownFromController
    }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**place/route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return {
      somethingFromNestedRoute: 'boooooyaaaaah'
    }
  }
});
```

**place/template.hbs**

```
<button {{action 'sendSomethingUp' model.somethingFromNestedRoute}}>
  Send model up
</button>
```

You might not need to send anything up with the action you're bubbling here. If that's the case then you can just grab what you need from the application controller or route and pass it down into `places-map`.

**places-map/template.hbs**

```
Insert something from the outer context:
<div>{{something}}</div>
```

[Here's an ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/be20d289a4f5dc945580?numColumns=1&openFiles=application.controller.js%2C&route=%2Fplace%2F1). I made a few notes in the `router.js` file that might be useful depending on the exact needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The data-down/actions-up Pattern is the answer.
http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/

You hold the data on a toplevel component/controller and pass the data down to child components. Data changes are triggered via actions on the child component and handled by the toplevel component/controller via action bubbling. So you need only one component/controller which knows how to change the data and how to get data.